# Flatten multiple SVG layers and save/export?

Tags: javascript, svg, canvas

I have created an avatar/character maker using many SVGs (all same width/height, position:absolute), arranged by z-index and selected using sliders.

It works well, but my goal is to now save a flattened version of the selected SVGs as a PNG to save/export. I have been researching canvas tags, but read I'll need to use multiple canvas tags as layers, which sounds like I'll be back to square one.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I have posted a snippet of my current code for clarity.

New to JS and SVG, and no experience with canvas, so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
    <body>
        <div class="image eyes" id="eyesImages">
            <img src="parts/eyes/01.svg">
            <img src="parts/eyes/02.svg">
            <img src="parts/eyes/03.svg">
        </div>
        <div class="image nose" id="noseImages">
            <img src="parts/nose/01.svg">
            <img src="parts/nose/02.svg">
            <img src="parts/nose/03.svg">
        </div>
        <div class="image mouth" id="mouthImages">
            <img src="parts/mouth/01.svg">
            <img src="parts/mouth/02.svg">
            <img src="parts/mouth/03.svg">
        </div>

        <div class="sliders">
            <div id="slider1">
                <label for="slider1">Eyes</label>
                <input type="range" min="1" max="50" value="1" class="slider" id="sliderEyes">
            </div>
            <div id="slider2">
                <label for="slider2">Nose</label>
                <input type="range" min="1" max="50" value="1" class="slider" id="sliderNose">
            </div>
            <div id="slider3">
                <label for="slider3">Mouth</label>
                <input type="range" min="1" max="50" value="1" class="slider" id="sliderMouth">
            </div>
        </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    
            var slider1 = document.getElementById("sliderEyes");
            var images = document.getElementById("eyesImages");
    
      slider1.addEventListener('input', function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < images.children.length; i++) {
          images.children[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
        i = Number(this.value) - 1;
        images.children[i].style.display = 'block';
      });
     });    
    
        window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    
            var slider2 = document.getElementById("sliderNose");
            var images = document.getElementById("noseImages");
    
      slider2.addEventListener('input', function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < images.children.length; i++) {
          images.children[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
        i = Number(this.value) - 1;
        images.children[i].style.display = 'block';
      });
     });
    
        window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    
            var slider3 = document.getElementById("sliderMouth");
            var images = document.getElementById("mouthImages");
    
      slider3.addEventListener('input', function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < images.children.length; i++) {
          images.children[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
        i = Number(this.value) - 1;
        images.children[i].style.display = 'block';
      });
     });
    </script>
</body>
```

Thanks

Comment: You only need one canvas. Set its resolution with `canvas,width` and `height` properties (not CSS values) and draw the SVG images in turn from bottom to top using the 2D context `drawImage(SVGImage, x, y);`  on the one canvas. You can then save as single PNG or JPG. info on 2D rendering context and more at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I fluked a fix and it works...

As the images are controlled by range sliders, I turned it into a form and pushed the values using POST on submit to another page with a canvas element. I defined the form values as variables and inserted them dynamically using PHP to draw a flat image with the corresponding numerical filenames, which I can now play with as needed.

However, if anyone has a sexier solution, please feel free to share. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can try [dom to image](https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image) library or [html2canvas](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas)

Here's an example of html2canvas on their respectful webiste https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/